# How to convert VGG from darknet to tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, yolo, vgg-net, openvino

I am trying to convert an existing VGG model (trained on 1 class) from Darknet format (including a .cfg file and .weights file) to the TensorFlow format. The end goal is to use the files in TensorFlow format with the Intel OpenVINO Toolkit.

As an initial attempt, I have tried using the [DW2TF](https://github.com/jinyu121/DW2TF) but encountered errors while running the program.

I first attempted with the official files provided on [pjreddie's website](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/imagenet/) and was met with the following error.

I am not specifically looking for a direct solution to the error below, instead I am looking for the best way I can convert VGG in Darknet format to TensorFlow, or any other pathways so that I can use the model with the Intel OpenVINO Toolkit. Any comments or suggestions are welcome.

Thanks for reading.

---

Command used:

```
python3 main.py\
--cfg data/vgg-16.cfg\
--weights data/vgg-16.weights\
--output output\
--gpu 0
```

Error received:

```
0 Tensor("network/net1:0", shape=(?, 256, 256, 3), dtype=float32)
=> Ignore:  {'name': 'crop', 'crop_height': '224', 'crop_width': '224', 'flip': '1', 'exposure': '1', 'saturation': '1', 'angle': '0'}
1 Tensor("network/net1:0", shape=(?, 256, 256, 3), dtype=float32)
2 Tensor("network/convolutional1/Activation:0", shape=(?, 256, 256, 64), dtype=float32)
3 Tensor("network/convolutional2/Activation:0", shape=(?, 256, 256, 64), dtype=float32)
4 Tensor("network/maxpool1/MaxPool:0", shape=(?, 128, 128, 64), dtype=float32)
5 Tensor("network/convolutional3/Activation:0", shape=(?, 128, 128, 128), dtype=float32)
6 Tensor("network/convolutional4/Activation:0", shape=(?, 128, 128, 128), dtype=float32)
7 Tensor("network/maxpool2/MaxPool:0", shape=(?, 64, 64, 128), dtype=float32)
8 Tensor("network/convolutional5/Activation:0", shape=(?, 64, 64, 256), dtype=float32)
9 Tensor("network/convolutional6/Activation:0", shape=(?, 64, 64, 256), dtype=float32)
10 Tensor("network/convolutional7/Activation:0", shape=(?, 64, 64, 256), dtype=float32)
11 Tensor("network/maxpool3/MaxPool:0", shape=(?, 32, 32, 256), dtype=float32)
12 Tensor("network/convolutional8/Activation:0", shape=(?, 32, 32, 512), dtype=float32)
13 Tensor("network/convolutional9/Activation:0", shape=(?, 32, 32, 512), dtype=float32)
14 Tensor("network/convolutional10/Activation:0", shape=(?, 32, 32, 512), dtype=float32)
15 Tensor("network/maxpool4/MaxPool:0", shape=(?, 16, 16, 512), dtype=float32)
16 Tensor("network/convolutional11/Activation:0", shape=(?, 16, 16, 512), dtype=float32)
17 Tensor("network/convolutional12/Activation:0", shape=(?, 16, 16, 512), dtype=float32)
18 Tensor("network/convolutional13/Activation:0", shape=(?, 16, 16, 512), dtype=float32)
19 Tensor("network/maxpool5/MaxPool:0", shape=(?, 8, 8, 512), dtype=float32)
=> Ignore:  {'name': 'connected', 'output': '4096', 'activation': 'relu'}
20 Tensor("network/maxpool5/MaxPool:0", shape=(?, 8, 8, 512), dtype=float32)
=> Ignore:  {'name': 'dropout', 'probability': '.5'}
21 Tensor("network/maxpool5/MaxPool:0", shape=(?, 8, 8, 512), dtype=float32)
=> Ignore:  {'name': 'connected', 'output': '4096', 'activation': 'relu'}
22 Tensor("network/maxpool5/MaxPool:0", shape=(?, 8, 8, 512), dtype=float32)
=> Ignore:  {'name': 'dropout', 'probability': '.5'}
23 Tensor("network/maxpool5/MaxPool:0", shape=(?, 8, 8, 512), dtype=float32)
=> Ignore:  {'name': 'connected', 'output': '1000', 'activation': 'linear'}
24 Tensor("network/maxpool5/MaxPool:0", shape=(?, 8, 8, 512), dtype=float32)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/acusensus/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1628, in _create_c_op
    c_op = c_api.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 8 for 'network/softmax1/Squeeze' (op: 'Squeeze') with input shapes: [?,8,8,512].

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 112, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "main.py", line 53, in main
    parse_net(args.layers, args.cfg, args.weights, args.training)
  File "main.py", line 33, in parse_net
    training=training, const_inits=const_inits, verbose=verbose)
  File "/home/acusensus/usb_accel_proj/DW2TF/util/cfg_layer.py", line 198, in get_cfg_layer
    layer = _cfg_layer_dict.get(layer_name, cfg_ignore)(B, H, W, C, net, param, weights_walker, stack, output_index, scope, training, const_inits, verbose)
  File "/home/acusensus/usb_accel_proj/DW2TF/util/cfg_layer.py", line 169, in cfg_softmax
    net = tf.squeeze(net, axis=[1, 2], name=scope+'/Squeeze')
  File "/home/acusensus/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 488, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/acusensus/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 2573, in squeeze
    return gen_array_ops.squeeze(input, axis, name)
  File "/home/acusensus/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 8236, in squeeze
    "Squeeze", input=input, squeeze_dims=axis, name=name)
  File "/home/acusensus/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/acusensus/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 488, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/acusensus/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3274, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/acusensus/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1792, in __init__
    control_input_ops)
  File "/home/acusensus/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1631, in _create_c_op
    raise ValueError(str(e))
ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 8 for 'network/softmax1/Squeeze' (op: 'Squeeze') with input shapes: [?,8,8,512].
```

Comment: I understand that I may not have asked the question perfectly. But for who ever has casted a down vote, could you please at least comment on a reason? I would like to improve in any way possible.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to look at below tutorial for a good guidance for converting Yolov3 for OpenVINO xml,bin format.

- https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/smart-video-workshop/blob/master/object-detection/README_yolov3.md

You should also check your version of Tensorflow, try downgrading it to 1.12. Methods in this tutorial worked for me.

Idea is to get weight conversion tool from

- https://github.com/mystic123/tensorflow-yolo-v3

Then, convert it using the convert_weights_pb.py script to make it ready for IR format conversion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have actually gotten the YOLOv3 working for both the default config and customized config using a similar workflow you described. The one I am currently having problem with is with the VGG classifier, which unfortunately still hasn't worked out yet.

Comment: I just downloaded the VGG config/weights from pjreddie. I managed to convert as I suggested above. 1) Downgrade to Tensorflow 1.12, 2) run `convert_weights_pb.py` and you have the frozen model in `.pb` format. I didn't tried for model optimizer yet.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up! Maybe I made a mistake somewhere along the conversion process. I will go back and go through the procedure again as you have suggested.

Comment: The tensorflow-yolo-v3 conversion tool runs but the output file does not work with the optimizer. One thing I found from the tensorflow-yolo-v3 source codes is that the routine is hard-coded for yolo-v3 or yolo-v3-tiny so they do not convert correctly.